# Converting weird characters and symbols into normal language in excel

Tags: excel, vba, text, unicode, utf

I am using the VBA code to extract information from a website into excel cells, and the numerical information is fine but I have a problem with text strings. I am mostly extracting information from Georgian websites, and the texts with the Georgian language are not properly displayed in excel, so I was wondering if there is any chance (code or something else) I could convert these symbols into proper language.

```
Sub GetData()

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant
Dim address As Variant
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Range

x = 1
Do Until x = 9
    Set y = Worksheets(1).Range("A21:A200"). _
    Find(x, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    website = "https://www.myhome.ge/ka/pr/11247371/iyideba-Zveli-ashenebuli-bina-veraze-T.-WoveliZis-qucha"
    
' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Where to go and how to go there.
request.Open "GET", website, False

' Get fresh data.
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

' Send the request for the webpage.
request.send

' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

' Put the webpage into an html object.
html.body.innerHTML = response

' Get info from the specified element on the page.
address = html.getElementsByClassName("address").Item(0).innerText
price = html.getElementsByClassName("d-block convertable").Item(0).innerText
  
y.Offset(0, 1).Value = address
y.Offset(0, 5).Value = price

x = x + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

This is the code that I took from a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOzHacoP-u4) and slightly modified, and it works, I just have a problem with how excel displays the characters in text strings.

[image]

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your issue. [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Comment: @gugu - You don't need this line `response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)`, Just assign responsetext to the innerhtml, `html.body.innerHTML = request.responseText`

Comment: Thank you very much @RaymondWu, your answer was extremely helpful and simple. I have been looking for this everywhere. Thank you again.

Comment: Also, would you happen to know why is the ID section not copied and pasted properly? It says [object HTMLPhraseElement] when it should actually copy the ID number of the property listed on the website (that I have put in the code). I have put the span class from the HTML in the VBA code (which is "id" for property ID) but it does not work. @RaymondWu

Comment: @gugu - I don't see anything in the code relating to ID (I only see `address` and `price`?) so I'm not exactly sure why your "code" is not working.

But assuming I'm correct in reading the website, try `Trim$(Replace(html.getElementsByClassName("id-container")(0).innerText, ":", vbNullString))`. In your example this would return `: 11247371` which I have applied `Replace` and `Trim$` functions to process the result.

Comment: It worked. Thank you again very much.

Answer (score 1):

**For your issue in the question**

1. Remove this line `response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)` as it's not required.
2. Change `html.body.innerHTML = response` to `html.body.innerHTML = request.responseText`.

**For your issue in comment**

To retrieve the ID of the property, it can be retrieved from the class `id-container`, you will need to perform some string processing though to remove the extract `:`

`propertyID = Trim$(Replace(html.getElementsByClassName("id-container")(0).innerText, ":", vbNullString))`

Note: You should try to avoid declaring variable as `Variant`. `innerText` property returns a `String` datatype so you should declare `address` and `price` as `String`.